# background image compressed horizontally

Tags: html, css, background-image

based on a recommendation ("css only technique number 1" here http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), i used an inline img element and css to make a background image that would fill the whole browser window.

it all works fine except that under a certain width of window, when the image resizes it starts compressing the image horizontally, in other words, not maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.

for instance, this jfiddle...if you move the browser around you can see honey boo boo's aspect ratio is not preserved.

http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/h7QMv/2/

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="gallery.html">
    <img  src="http://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/tv-honey_boo_boo.jpg" class="bg "/>
    </a>
  </div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: my image is 1280 px wide, btw

Comment: Could you please create a jsFiddle so that we can tinker?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/h7QMv/1/   see how if you stretch the page up and down Honey Boo Boo stretches vertically? it performs fine when the page is larger, but past 600 pixels freaks out.

Comment: Just for S&G, change this part of the CSS for me and see what you notice: `img.bg {left: 0%; margin-left: -0px;}`

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do on resize? Keeping a fixed aspect ratio is easy, just set height to 100% with no width set.

Comment: @DevlshOne still has the same problem

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk yea but then it won't fill the entire browser horizontally. the idea is to always have the window totally filled while also preserving aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the CSS3 method described first in the post - It's a simpler and more reliable method:

```
html { 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: i did this, but i want specifically to understand the implementation of the method i described. also that method requires creating an additional blank div to use the background image as a link to another page. this way would do it automatically.

Comment: you could always add a body onclick event with this method... but.... give me a second

Comment: how would i do that body onclick event? that seems like a good option.

Comment: okay but then how do i get users to know it's clickable? like there's no white glove pointing hand thing now? edit: that may be because i didn't implement it right, i'm re-reading how to implement onclick right now...i cut and pasted what you wrote with my own link in place of yoursite, but it didn't work

Comment: <body onClick="window.location.href = 'http://whatever.com'"> and set your css for the body tag as so > body{cursor:pointer;}

Comment: <body onclick="window.location.href='www.google.com';">  i tried this and it won't click through to anything. i can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: this should work to do both things, but still, it's just not working. <body onclick="window.location.href='google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ytw8/ include this on your page instead. body onclick event issues... not sure

Comment: if i could get the page to click, we'd be good to go, because i have it working now through another way.

Comment: right, the cursor is good, but the click through still doesn't work on that jfiddle or on mine.

Comment: nice! now i just have to look up how to call js from html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using img element, you can just *apply the background image to the div* (or any other container stretched accordingly to the browser borders).

Then, you do the following for the background:

```
.picture {
    background-image: url(...);

    background-size:cover; /* this way */
    background-size:content; /* or this one (which you prefer) */
}
```

... to stretch the image accordingly to its container size.

**EDIT:**

Also, in this very case:

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container-fluid
{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-position:center;
}
```

(But this is an example -- you should play with your layouts by your own then).

Comment: i couldn't get this to work, can you show me in this jfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/h7QMv/2/

Comment: Yes. Please, have a look at the jfiddle.

Comment: did you save the jfiddle? because it's just my original one, still with the aspect problem.

Comment: this is working great, but the problem is now i've changed my style sheet to have this as the background on every page, which it's not.